# Navigation (display?) for sliding Fragments

Tags: java, android, layout

i would like to have some kind of navigation display for my sliding fragments (i don't really know how to explain this better) something like you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StyEv.jpg) (the little dots down is what i want).

I already have the sliding fragments working just would love to have some kind of indicator that shows where you actually are when sliding through them.

Thanks for any kind of advice!!

Comment: Please don't post links to code, include a [mcve] in your question. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of trying to be ironical, you should actually read this site's [ask] and [answer] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add pager indicator by using the following code through radio group

Code Written in **Kotlin**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_test.*
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity(){ 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

 customImageAdapter = MyCustomPagerAdapter(this@TestActivity, numbers)
        vpIntro.adapter = customImageAdapter
    /* Add Circle indicator for view the current page*/
        addRadioButtons(4, rgPagerIndicator)

vpIntro.setOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                currentPos = position
                rgPagerIndicator.check(position)
            }
        })
}
```

Add Radio Button function

```
fun addRadioButtons(number: Int, rgPager: RadioGroup) {//, radioButtons: java.util.ArrayList<RadioButton>
//        radioButtons.clear()
        rgPager.removeAllViews()
        if (number > 1) {
            for (i in 0 until number) {
                val params_button: RadioGroup.LayoutParams
                val device_height = 1184

                val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
                val size = Point()
                display.getSize(size)
                val width = size.x
                val height = size.y

                if (device_height == height) {
                    params_button = RadioGroup.LayoutParams(25, 25)
                    params_button.setMargins(7, 0, 7, 0)
                } else {
                    params_button = RadioGroup.LayoutParams(35, 35)
                    params_button.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)
                }

                val rdbtn = RadioButton(this@WelcomeActivity)
                rdbtn.isEnabled = false
                rdbtn.id = i
                rdbtn.layoutParams = params_button
                rdbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_viewpager_indicator)
                rdbtn.setButtonDrawable(R.color.transparent)
                if (i == 0) {
                    rdbtn.isChecked = true
                }

                rgPager.addView(rdbtn)
            }
        }
    }
```

Take one Radio group below your view pager in xml

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found a way to have this fragment display, with the help/inspiration of Nielsh response i implemented a java variant. First add the RadioGroup to your MainActivity.xml

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:checked="true" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Initialize your radiobutton group, then just add an onPageListener to your ViewPager and init

```
        (...)
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        (...)
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            page = position;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton3);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    }); // viewpager on page change listener
```